# Concisely writing multiple similar constraints for an optimization problem

Tags: inequality, notation, constraints

I am currently studying the linear optimization problems and would like to know if it is possible to make the notation for multiple similar constraints more concise.

For example, I know how to do that if you variables have integer subscripts($x_1,x_2,x_3...$). Then, if we have similar constraints on each variable, instead of writing it this way
$$
x_1 \le 20
\\ x_2 \le 20
\\ x_3 \le 20
$$
We could simply write $x_i \le 20\ (i=1..3)$. But how can we do something similar when the variables are named more conveniently, for ex. $x_a,x_m,x_d$? ($a,m,d$ are not integers anymore). Would writing something like $x_i \le 20\ (i\in\{a,m,d\})$ be incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you wrote is correct.  Another option is to let $I=\{a,m,d\}$ and then write the constraints as $x_i \le 20$ for $i\in I$.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've just come up with one more way of writing the constraints. Would $x\ge20,x\in\{x_a,x_m,x_d\}$ be also acceptable? And I think that defining a set would also be more convenient because it would allow us to write something like this $x_i\ge20,i \in I -\{d\}$ (set $I$ excluding element $d$) For some reason I can't make the set exclusion render correctly, so using a minus here

Comment: No, writing $x\in\{x_a,x_m,x_d\}$ is at best nonstandard.  To get $I \setminus\{d\}$, use \setminus.

Comment: Thanks again, noted!